# Are dict comprehensions inefficient...is there a faster way to compare to keys and values in two dicts?

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a problem in which two strings are given as arguments and the task is to determine if the first string contains all the elements necessary to make the second string. I thought I had a fairly straightforward solution by creating dictionaries from the two strings, where the keys are the characters in the strings and the values are their respective number of appearances. Here's the code:

```
    def scramble(s1, s2):
        s1dict = {x: s1.count(x) for x in s1}
        s2dict = {y: s2.count(y) for y in s2}
        s3dict = {k:s2dict[k] for k in s2dict and s1dict[k] >= s2dict[k]}
        return s3dict == s2dict
```

When I try to submit the solution into the web challenge interpreter, it says my code is timing out. I know that for large strings this solution is causing a lot of iteration...What approach can I take to make this more efficent?

Comment: `{x: s1.count(x) for x in s1}` is O(N^2). Use `collections.Counter` as a drop-in replacement

Comment: Dict comprehensions aren't inherently inefficient, your *algorithm* is: `{x: s1.count(x) for x in s1}` is needlessly inefficient. Instead of a linear time operation you are getting a quadratic time operation because .count is linear on the length of s1. Also, `{k:s2dict[k] for k in s2dict and s1dict[k] >= s2dict[k]}` is not doing what you think it is doing... what are you trying to do with `and` there?

Comment: I'm trying to check that the keys are in both dicts, AND that the corresponding integer values for the keys in the first dict are >= to their counterparts in the second dict. Is the `and` not accomplishing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, dictionary comprehension is not inherently inefficient. If you want to speed up your solution, you should take a look at your algorithm.

`s1dict = {x: s1.count(x) for x in s1}` is an inefficient way of getting the counts of all characters in `s1`. If `s1` is length N, this will iterate through `s1` N times, making it O(N^2). If you were to implement that logic yourself, it would look something like this:

```
s1dict = {}
for char1 in s1:
    for char2 in s1:
        if char2 == char1:
            s1dict[char1] = s1dict.get(char1, 0) + 1
```

There is a way to get the counts in O(N) time.

```
s1dict = {}
for char in s1:
    s1dict[char] = s1dict.get(char, 0) + 1
```

Alternatively, you can use `collections.Counter` to do this for you: `s1dict = collections.Counter(s1)`.

The way you compute your s3dict is actually invalid. I also don't think that dictionary comprehension is the best way to compare the two dictionaries anyway. You could use dictionary comprehension (`all({k: s1dict.get(k, 0) >= v for k, v in s2dict.items()})`) but why not just write a simple loop?

```
for key, value in s2dict.items():
    if s1dict.get(key, 0) < value:
        return False
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def check_words(one, two):
        # theses are characters the two strings have
        # this prevents looping over the same character when checking counts latter
        shared = set(one + two)

        # these are the number of each share string the have in dict format
        one_count = {letter: one.count(letter) for letter in shared}
        two_count = {letter: two.count(letter) for letter in shared}

        # confirm both strings posses the characters need to form them
        if one_count == two_count:
            print(True)



    check_words("hello", "lehol")
```

Comment: I liked your idea of implementing the set to reduce the amount of looping, but because the set removes duplicates it turned out that the code didn't give the correct output for what I'm trying to do. If the first string has duplicates of letters in the second string, the code in your `if one_count == two_count` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this question while searching for a solution to my coding issue. I am wondering why no one is mentioning the use of a simple loop:

```
def func(str1, str2):
    for char in str2:
        if not char in str1:
            return False
    return True
```

Is there something I'm missing about why this is not a valid approach?